# Attempting to pattern match with Strings in Racket to append them together

Tags: racket

I am trying to have my program add a string to another string, if in the right format.

My current code is

```
(define (addString e)
 (match e
   [`(+ , x, y) (string-append x y)]))
```

So when I run (addString (+ "a" "b")) it returns "ab"

However, it gives an error: "match: no matching clause for `+". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there! you just need to quote the input. Also, the `,` inside the match clause should be written right besides the variable you want to evaluate (although it works the way you have it, but it can be a little confusing). This is what I mean:

```
(define (addString e)
 (match e
   [`(+ ,x ,y) (string-append x y)]))
```

It works as expected:

```
(addString '(+ "a" "b"))
=> "ab"
```

Comment: Thank you. Is the ',' next to the variable thing just a good coding practice or are there cases where it could give me results I don't want?

Comment: The “,”  next to the variable is how you’re expected to use it, it makes clear that you want to evaluate that variable as part of a quasiquoting expression. At risk of stating the obvious, but in Scheme the commas are not used for separating elements in lists, here they have a different purpose and we want to make it extra explicit